# How to handle data put in table in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble handling my data to put in table. And then I have an object array

```
[
    {
        no: 1,
        name: 'Alpha Team',
        type: 'Project 1'
    },
    {
        no: 2,
        name: 'Beta Team',
        price: 'Project 1'
    },
    {
        no: 3,
        name: 'Beta Team',
        type: 'Project 2'
    },
    {
        no: 4,
        name: 'Beta Team',
        type: 'Project 3'
    }
]
```

I want to put it in a table with the same name as 1 row and the other data will concatenate in the column like
[image]

How should I handle it?

Comment: Have you tried "rowspan" and "colspan" attributes in <td> tag?

Comment: yes i don't know how to handle data put in it.